# How can I use an Indian 2.1 speaker in United States?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, transformer, speakers

I purchased a 2.1 (2 speakers , 1 sub-woofer) Creative Inspire audio system in India a few years back. I loved the sound quality so much that I brought it all the way to United States, forgetting that the line voltage required to drive the speaker is `220V` while US power supply is `110V`. When plugged to US power line, the audio system is producing sound almost inaudible to human ears! Do I need a step-up transformer or something similar to make it work in US?

Comment: Attention: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/120983/what-happens-if-a-240v-appliance-is-connected-in-a-120v-ac-power-supply

Comment: @Swanand, yes I agree that the "rules" here seem arbitrary and unevenly applied. I have yet to make any sense out of them. Other SE forums are even more bizarre, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities. It is just barely possible that your speakers have a voltage select switch which will allow you to run on 110. Maybe. Check where the power line enters your speakers, and you might get lucky.

Probably not, though. In that case, yes, you'll need to get a 110 to 220 transformer, which will be pricey, although you don't need much power. A good place to start is Amazon - search for "step up power transformer".